# How to find element by watir-webdriver using more than one class?

Tags: html, css, ruby, selenium, watir-webdriver

For example, we have element like this:
`<div class="first_class second_class"></div>`

So we can find using it's classes:

- `browser.div(class: 'first_class')`
- `browser.div(class: 'second_class')`

But what is about multiple search? Can I use combination of them?

- `browser.div(class: 'first_class second_class')`?
- `browser.div(class: 'second_class first_class')`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, use a CSS selector directly:

```
browser.div(css: '.first_class.second_class')
```

Note that the "by class" locator is actually transformed to a "by CSS selector" under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

For multiple values:

```
<div class="first_class second_class"></div>
```

You can specify as an array:

```
div(class: ["first_class"], ["second_class"])
```

Separated by comma `,` can be added more values to an array:

```
div(class: ["first_class"], ["second_class"], ["third_class"])
```